# rShiny failing to parse HTML

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Consider the following app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

tab_example <-
  tabItem(tabName = "example",
          fluidRow(
            column(6,
                   h4("example"),
                   includeHTML("example.html")
            )
          )
  )

body <-
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tab_example
    )
  )

sidebar <-
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Example", tabName = "example", icon = icon("bullseye"))
    )
  )

ui <-
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "EXAMPLE"),
    sidebar,
    body
  )

server <- function(input, output) {


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Wherein `example.html`:

```
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
```

This runs as it should, but when running a more sophisticated example with a folder structure it fails to parse.

Folder Structure:

```
├── example
│   └── example.html
├── dashboard.R
├── ui_elements
│   └── sidebar.R
│   └── body.R
│   └── tabs
│    └── tab_example.R
```

`tab_example.R`:

```
source("example/example.html")

tab_example <-
  tabItem(tabName = "example",
          fluidRow(
            column(6,
                   includeHTML("example.html")
            )
          )
  )
```

The error message is:

```
 Error in source("example/example.html") : 
  example/example.html:1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <
```

Is there something I need to do in `source("example/example.html")` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the help from `source`, the header says:

> Read R Code from a File, a Connection or Expressions

However, you try to read an HTML file, therefore it fails. You can just specify the correct path in `includeHTML`:

```
includeHTML("example/example.html")
```

and don't need to use `source`